# Security implications of running eval() on user-generated input in an iFrame (angularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-scope

I know using `eval()` on user input is generally not safe, but in this certain use-case, I want to know if I can get around the negative security implications. I have an `iframe` which looks something like this (note that this is a `template` so it's being embedded on a page by another file):

HTML:

```
<iframe>
<html ng-app="iframe">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/iframe.js"></script>
<body id="body" ng-controller="iFrameCtrl">
<script id="myscript" type="text/javascript">
    var color = 'orange';
    console.log(color);
    stage.update();
</script>
</html>
</iframe>
```

And the `iframe.js`:

```
angular.module('iframe', [])
.controller('iFrameCtrl', ($scope){
    //external user input that modifies 'color' variable in #myscript
    //$scope.$watching brings external variable changes into this function
    var scriptElem = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myscript'));
    scriptText = scriptElem[0].innerText;
    $scope.$apply();
    eval(scriptText);
});
```

The basic gist is there's a user input (from outside the `iframe` which is modifying the color variable, changing `var color = 'orange'` to `var color = 'blue'`, or something similar—where `eval()` is causing the script to be re-executed and the new `color` to be applied).

Can this be done safely? In terms of XSS attacks, etc.

My initial impressions would be yes—all script is being executed within the iFrame. Also, Angular has the ability to use directives to only accept strings into input fields which coincide with programmatically established rules. (i.e. I can have an input field only evaluate to `true` if it follows an established format).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpopular answer: You are fine, as long as you check that nothing malicious is being done. From my experience, anyone can execute anything in any case by opening up your console. **The real danger comes in when malicious scripts are written to a database** and called next time the page loads (for another user). Allowing eval is only going to affect the person who is executing the script. XSS scripting happens when someone injects their own code into your page, typically by creating a link somewhere to malicious scripts which will load for **other users** (not just the person who is doing the bad stuff).

Comment: This is correct.  Often times "eval on user input is bad" is not qualified with "...if the user input is saved in a database and eval'd other users sessions".

Comment: +1 for not just saying "eval is bad". Malicious code is actually fine too, what matters is really only whether it reaches other users or not. I think the words "other users" deserve emphasising. :)

Comment: You all make valid points, however, 9 times out of 10 if you find yourself using eval, there is generally a far better way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to achieve. Not to mention, if your code has to be checked for PCI compliance.

Comment: I am not sure I agree, to be sure, I cannot remember the last time I actually did use eval, but it does work pretty awesome when evaluating mathematical operations. Would you use eval or build your own compiler for a javascript calculator?

Comment: I had to write a calculator for a code challenge, pre-interview. There was no use of eval :) On a lower level, when the compiler encounters eval, it prevents your code from being optimized for the interpreter.

Comment: eval() isn’t evil, just misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

There really is no need to eval here.

I would suggest going the semantic route, and using cross document messaging, especially if you are only changing one property. It should be a lot less intensive as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

As far as security, it really depends, but the convention is there for a reason.